# Find private inner class using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

In the context of android.accounts.AccountManager:

```
public class AccountManager {

    private abstract class AmsTask extends FutureTask<Bundle> implements AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> {
    ...
    }

}
```

I would like to find the inner class by name using reflection, as I require a `Class` object to determine staticness of member methods. In the simple case

```
public class AccountManager {

    public class Foo {
    ...
    }

}
```

This can be done using `Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager$Foo")`. However, the `private` modifier eliminates this possibility. I tried searching through `Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager").getDeclaredClasses()`, but it returns an empty list. Its [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses()) covers `private` member classes, so I am at a loss why it is not returned by the getter. <s>I presume it has something to do with `abstract`.</s>

EDIT: Experiments have shown `getDeclaredClasses()` to work with the following snippet, but not with the actual Android class.

```
public class Test {

    private abstract class AmsTask extends LinkedList implements TestInterface {
    ...
    }

    private interface TestInterface{}

}
```

The suggestion that using AccountManager's class loader might help, did not turn out to be fruitful.

```
Class am = Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager");
Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask",false,am);
```

resulted in a `ClassNotFoundException` during the latter call.

Comment: A simplified example works fine here: http://ideone.com/Bq24O3.  Could you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please explain why you need that class, otherwise you seem to have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Most interesting. I just extended your example by having the inner class also extend `LinkedList` and implement a custom interface. Still `getDeclaredClasses()` worked fine.

Comment: I have a list of method signatures such as `Landroid/accounts/AccountManager$AmsTask;->set(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V` and am using reflection to determine whether each of them is static. For that I need a `Class` object on which I can call `getMethod()` and then `Modifier.isStatic()`. Some of the classes involved are private inner classes.

Comment: For above mentioned reason, I cannot construct a minimal test case. All I can really do is provide your with the source code of `AccountManager`, in hopes that it sheds light on the issue.

Comment: The example is working because a) the code is running within the same package and/or b) the code is running from the same class loader.  I think maybe the class loader could have some bearing; you could try the `forName` variant with `AccountManager`'s class loader as a parameter and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the following was your suggestion: `Class am = Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager"); Class ams = Class.forName("android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask",false,am.getClassLoader());` Unfortunately, that didn't work - getting a `ClassNotFoundException` during the latter call to `forName()`.

Comment: I updated the description to reflect the results achieved in the comment section to avoid confusion.

Comment: Err, moment please. If honourable programmer wish to find class, why is it private?

Comment: When monitoring an apps' execution you might be interested in calls to private class methods that leak user data to third parties.